# Can we use action.payload on multiple object keys?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to add tasks to my Todo app with this action:

```
addTask: (state, action) => {
      const newTask = {
        id: uuidv4(),
        text: action.payload,
        completed: false,
        date: action.payload,
      };
      state.push(newTask);
    },
```

Which will be dispatched in this way to show both text and date:

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!inputFieldSlice || !dateSlice) return;

    dispatch(addTask(`${inputFieldSlice} on: ${dateSlice}`));

    dispatch(clearInputField(""));
    dispatch(clearDate(""));
  };
```

The output will be something like this: **Shopping on: 2021-11-03**

I wanted to know if this is the right way to do this and if I can actually pass `action.payload` to two different keys in an object.

Comment: You can pass it to all the keys you want.  This would make more sense if you were to pass the string to the `text` field and a proper time stamp to the `date` field.  You get your display value and a way to perform date ordering functions if you do it that way.  Also you shouldn't be passing entire slices.  Hopefully you just need better variable names there.

Comment: @jmargolisvt I'm actually realizing that my approach is not correct. When passing date the action.payload, I'm also getting the text of input field into it so both text and date have the value of Shopping on: 2021-11-03

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`action.payload` doesn't have to be a string. You don't even need to name it `payload` or `action`. You could simply pass an object as the payload with any keys you want. I chose `text` and `date` in this case:

```js
addTask: (state, action) => {
  const newTask = {
    id: uuidv4(),
    text: action.payload.text,
    completed: false,
    date: action.payload.date,
  };
  state.push(newTask);
},

// ...

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!inputFieldSlice || !dateSlice) return;

  dispatch(
    addTask({
      text: inputFieldSlice,
      date: dateSlice,
    }),
  );

  dispatch(clearInputField(''));
  dispatch(clearDate(''));
};
```

By storing them separately, when you render the task, you can render it like this:

```js
<ul>
  {tasks.map((task) => (
    <li key={task.id}>
      {task.text} on: {task.date}
    </li>
  ))}
</ul>
```